# Removing array elements

Tags: perl, arrays

how do I remove an element from a Perl array ref? I've got its index and I don't want to set the element to `undef`, but to remove it completely.

For example, how do I change `$a = [1, 2, 3];` into `$a = [1, 3];`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [splice()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) :

```
splice @$a, 1, 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html):

```
my @array = (44,55,66);
splice @array, 1, 1; # 55
@array; # (44,66)

my $array_ref = [44,55,66];
splice @{ $array_ref }, 1, 1; # 55
$array_ref; # (44,66)
```

I have noticed that you are confused about data types and references because Devel::REPL displays them in the reference form only. You defined an array reference in the question, not an array. Compare my code examples.

Comment: I'm ok with the types, but forget to name them correctly, since I only have to write Perl by accident ;) Correcting the question.